# Running the Bin file with get.Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

This the C++ code for hello.exe:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int  main()
{
  cout<<"Hello world\n";
  getch();
  cout<<"I bypass error\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I need to run hello.exe from a Java program.

I want to learn Java in order to call the sub process bin file and send control execution by the IO to those bin files.

Like in this hello.exe, it will print the hello world and if I and able to enter the value then only I am able to see the "I bypass error".

This is my Java program:

```
package procs;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Procs
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      try
      {
         int exitVal;
         char c = 'a';
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:/hello.exe"});
         OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
         InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
         InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
         //PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(stdin));
         //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
         // i uses both printstream and Buffered writer

         System.out.println("lets start<<<<<<");
         do
         {
            c = (char)reader.read();
            System.out.print(c);
         }
         while (c != '\n');
         //writer.Print(c);  i uses  both print
         //writer.write(c);  and the writer
         writer.flush();
         do
         {
            c = (char)reader.read();
            System.out.print(c);
         }
         while (c != '\n');
         exitVal = process.waitFor();
         System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

It hangs after the `lets start<<<<<`

It does not even show hello world

Also help me with this part:

```
exitVal=process.waitFor();
```

Like this does we have some pause command to pause the execution of the process

Comment: You need to call `cout.flush();` to get the output of the sub process.

Comment: i reached to hello world after using cout.flush. but now problem is that  at c++ getch() ...  java program is  unable to send writer.write() or writer.print() to that....

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `getch();` does not work. Use

```
int a;
cin>>a;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
writer.write(c);
writer.flush();
```

the statements above write to `stdin` of the sub-process  but `getch()` seems to not read from `stdin` since it is not getting the input. You should use `cin >> c;`  or `c = getc(stdin)` instead. `getch()` even seem to have some weird effect with on `stdout` since replacing it makes flushing `cout` obsolete.

Here is some working code:

```
// C++

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    cout<<"Hello world\n";
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    cout<<"input received "  << c << endl;
    cout<<"I bypass error\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
// Java

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

System.out.println("lets start<<<<<<");
do {
 c = (char) reader.read();
   System.out.print(c);
} while (c != '\n' && c != -1 && c != Character.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.print('\n');
System.out.print("(1) stdout of subprocess consumed.");

c = (char) System.in.read();
writer.write(c);
writer.flush();


do {
 c = (char) reader.read();
   System.out.print(c);
} while (c != '\n' && c != -1 && c != Character.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.print('\n');
System.out.print("(2) stdout of subprocess consumed.");

exitVal = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
```

This statement

```
exitVal=process.waitFor();
```

just means that the current thread - the main-thread in your case - has to wait for the sub-process to finish and catches the value it returns (see the javadoc from [Process#waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)). This value is the one returned by `return 0;` in the C++ program.

**Output**

```
lets start<<<<<<
Hello world

(1) stdout of subprocess consumed.a
input received a

(2) stdout of subprocess consumed.Exited with error code 0
```

Note that the `a` right after `(1) ... consumed.` is just the input in the console, it is not part of the output.